# How to have windows inside of tabs in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have been banging my head on this for a few days.

I want to have a few windows that live inside a tab in ExtJS. I have tried creating windows in the tab but when you switch tabs the windows stay visible so they are not bound to the tab. Also the windows must be able to be dynamically created/destroyed.

I have tried creating a window and then using tab.add(wind) to add it to the frame of the tab but that didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK windows can't be nested inside anything, they're a floating panel basically

Comment: I think the question is: Why do you specifically want it to be a window? What is it that you want from your control that a `panel` cannot do?

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution, you can hide() and show() a window before a tabpanel is activated/deactivated.

That is, if a user moves out of a tab, then you can hide all the windows so that they are not displayed in other tabs, and when user moves back to this tab, then you can display all such windows back. Of course, you will have to put a check on whether windows are existing or not. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the tab's deactivate and activate listeners:

This is tested in extjs 4.1

```
this.tab_panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    activeTab: 0,
    border:false,
    items: [{
        ..... // your other tab config
        listeners:
        {
            activate:
            {
                scope: yourscope,
                fn: function()
                {
                    var window = this.windowThatsInATab;    // or panel etc...

                    window.floatingItems.show();
                }
            },
            deactivate:
            {
                scope: yourscope,
                fn: function()
                {
                    var window = this.windowThatsInATab;    // or panel etc...

                    window.floatingItems.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```